# Codename One: 2d Drawing app

Tags: codenameone

I would like to know, where do I initialise my DrawingCanvas class (referred in 2d drawing app) using the GUI Builder (old one).

Also, how would I change the stroke color for each button that refers to the GUI Builder?

```
package userclasses;
import com.codename1.ui.Component;
import com.codename1.ui.Form;
import com.codename1.ui.events.ActionEvent;
import generated.StateMachineBase;
import com.codename1.ui.util.Resources;
/**
 *
 * @author Your name here
 */

public class StateMachine extends StateMachineBase{
    public StateMachine(String resFile) {
        super(resFile);
        // do not modify, write code in initVars and initialize class members there,
        // the constructor might be invoked too late due to race conditions that might occur
    }

    /**
     * this method should be used to initialize variables instead of
     * the constructor/class scope to avoid race conditions
     */
    @Override
    protected void initVars(Resources res) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The source for that class is in the [graphics section of the Codename One  developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/manual/graphics.html), pasted below:

> The center of the app is the DrawingCanvas class, which extends Component.

```
public class DrawingCanvas extends Component {
    GeneralPath p = new GeneralPath();
    int strokeColor = 0x0000ff;
    int strokeWidth = 10;

    public void addPoint(float x, float y){
        // To be written
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintBackground(Graphics g) {
        super.paintBackground(g);
            Stroke stroke = new Stroke(
                strokeWidth,
                Stroke.CAP_BUTT,
                Stroke.JOIN_ROUND, 1f
            );
            g.setColor(strokeColor);

            // Draw the shape
            g.drawShape(p, stroke);

    }

    @Override
    public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
        addPoint(x-getParent().getAbsoluteX(), y-getParent().getAbsoluteY());
    }
}
```

Notice that this is the base skeleton and more code is added later in that chapter...